# How to write a php unit test case for symfony controller

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to write a unit test case for symfony controller.

**Controller Code**

```
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class Controller1 extends SecuredController
{

public function preExecute(Request $request) {
    parent::preExecute($request);
}

public function indexAction()
{
    return $this->render('help/index.html.twig');
}
```

I have tried writing a test case as shown below but it throws an ***internal error***

```
namespace Tests\AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;

class Controller1Test extends WebTestCase
{
public function testIndex()
 {
   $client = static::createClient();

    $response = $client->getResponse();

    $this->assertEquals(200, $response->getStatusCode());

}
}
```

Any suggestion would be helpful for me

Comment: Short answer for how to unit test a controller: you don't.  Take a look at the Symfony functional test capability and spend a bit of time browsing the many many identical questions on this topic.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, is a UNIT test. You here dont need a client. You just need the class you want to test.

```
namespace Tests\AppBundle\Controller;

use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;
use AppBundle\Controller\Controller1;

class Controller1Test extends TestCase
{
    public function testIndex()
    {
        $this->request = $this->getMockBuilder(
            'Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request'
        )->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->getMock();

        $controller = new Controller1();
        $controller->preExecute($this->request);
        $response = $controller->indexAction();
        $this->assertEquals(
            200,
            $response->getStatusCode()
        );
    }
}
```

and for example your code could be

```
namespace Tests\AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class Controller1 extends SecuredController
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        return new Response();
    }
}
```

Comment: But My controller expects request as a input for preExecute() method and indexAction() will render a twig file.

Comment: I've update my answer. PS is useless to overwrite a method that have same behavior of parent class.

Comment: But, ... Why you need to call preExecute? Who call preExecute function? Which version of symfony are you using?

Comment: Symfony 2.7..Usually I use preExecute function for getting services from container and performing some actions before methods are called in the controller

Comment: No. I get the following error Argument 1 passed to AppBundle\Controller\Controller1::preExecute() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request, instance of Mock_Response_8d332c79 given, called in /home/tivizio/slave/workspace/test_rtu2bss/src/AppBundle/Tests/Controller/Controller1Test.php

Comment: I've update mock class with "Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request"

Comment: Have you experiences in mocks?

Comment: No I am very new to mocks.After changing that I have problem with parent class. Following is the error : Call to a member function get() on null in /home/tivizio/slave/workspace/test_rtu2bss/src/AppBundle/Controller/SecuredController

Comment: I've tried your answer, but I get `Fatal error: Call to a member function has() on a non-object in ...\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller.php on line 339` when my controller calls `$doctrine = $this->getDoctrine();`.